# Lottery odds when order matters?

Tags: probability

Let's say there is a lottery where one can play 10 numbers chosing from a total of 20. The lottery will pull out 10 numbers randomly. What's the chance that the first 2 number played exactly match (order included) the first 2 of the lottery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hence of symmetry we can assume the first two chosen numbers are $(1,2)$. This because your ambiguity when choosing $(1,2)$ is as much as choosing $(2,3)$ or any other couple, therefore $$\Pr(\text{being matched}|(x,y)\text{ have been chosen})=\Pr(\text{being matched}|(w,z)\text{ have been chosen})$$let's define$$P_{x,y}=\Pr(\text{being matched}|(x,y)\text{ have been chosen})$$then we can obtain$$\Pr(\text{being matched}){=\sum_{(x,y)}\Pr(\text{choosing (x,y)})P_{x,y}\\=P_{x,y}\sum_{(x,y)}\Pr(\text{choosing (x,y)})\\=P_{x,y}\\=P_{1,2}}$$ then the probability is $$P=\Pr((x,y)=(1,2))=\dfrac{1}{2\binom{20}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{380}$$

Comment: what's the basic reasoning?

Comment: This because your ambiguity when choosing $(1,2)$ is as much as choosing $(2,3)$ or any other couple. Therefore $$\Pr(\text{being matched}|(x,y)\text{ have been chosen})=\Pr(\text{being matched}|(w,z)\text{ have been chosen})$$

Comment: the guy picks 10 numbers(out of 20) where only the first two matches the house number. How doh you comoute all the favorable permutations?

Comment: 'cause once the first two numbers matched pairwise we don't care the others e.g. (1,2,5,6,4,6,7,8,6,4) and $(1,2,4,5,6,5,4,3,4,4)$ are equal for us and for the lottery

Comment: kk I was overcomplicating things

Comment: Hope it helps you ^__^

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. What is the chance that the first number matches?
2. What is the chance that the second number matches? (It's not the same as above. Why not?)

Comment: 45/1847560? maybe